# Issure with Facebook social plugin comment

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-comments

I use Facebook social plugin comment. When I enter a comment, modal show with title "Opps" but no content, my comment still be created.
Here is my err: POST lrIDktcrT-0.js:31 POST https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments/async/createComment/10150210921790548/?dpr=1 500 ()

```
AsyncRequest.send @ lrIDktcrT-0.js:31
M @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:325
G @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:325
(anonymous) @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:325
j.__invokeCallback @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:20
j.$Dispatcher_DEPRECATED7 @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:20
j.dispatch @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:20
j.$DevxFluxDispatcher1 @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:299
j.handleViewAction @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:299
(anonymous function) @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:300
(anonymous) @ mDaPM9z_i0f.js:346
J @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:46
h @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:41
g @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
g @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
og @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
pg @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Di @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Fi @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Ai @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
g @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Ki @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
g @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Wi @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Eg @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Eg @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
Gg @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
g @ jeoyZtjV1Ng.js:40
J @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:46
x @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:220
x @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:220
(anonymous) @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:214
I @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:64
N @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:64
u @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:214
J @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:46
N @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:64
(anonymous) @ 1Dk5dwOP3va.js:63
```

And here is my code:

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId={my_app_id}';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</body>
```